# Is it possible to set variable in html / js file without defining it in ModelAndView in spring boot application?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to implement Google Recaptcha for few html files. To works properly, I need to put public key in html and js files. Can I do it without sending these keys by ModelAndView?

I would like it to be read directly from the application.porpertis or something like this. It is possible?

Comment: Set in request or session object. Get it from request/ session  object

Comment: Reading from property file is possible, do some research. There are plenty of examples available